# How to make jQuery script apply to multiple html tables

Tags: jquery, html, each

I'm pretty new to jQuery but have managed to develop a script which manipulates the heights of th and td tags at particular breakpoints. It basically looks for the highest th or td in each row of a given table and applies that height to all th and td tags in that particular row, then moves on to the next row etc.

The script is necessary because of a faulty Wordpress plugin which wrongly alters the appearance of tables at particular breakpoints. The plugin is core to our development and cannot be changed, so we have to use jQuery to manipulate the table's appearance.

Everything works fine, but now I need it to work for multiple tables displayed on any given page.

Each table has the class 'tablepress' and I have tried surrounding our script with

```
$('table.tablepress').each(function() {

...our script...

})
```

but that isn't working and the logic is breaking my mind :)

Here's our script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(window).resize(function(){

    //get breakpoint as defined in table classes (desktop,tablet,phone)

    var responsivemode = $("#tablepress-999-no-2").attr('class').split(/ |-/); 
    var breakpoint = 0;
    if($.inArray('desktop',responsivemode) > -1){
        var breakpoint = 1200;
    }else if($.inArray('tablet',responsivemode) > -1){
        var breakpoint = 980;
    }else if($.inArray('phone',responsivemode) > -1){
        var breakpoint = 768;
    }else{
        var breakpoint = 0;
    }

    //only manipulate table if breakpoint reached

    if (parseInt($(window).width()) < breakpoint) {

    var myobject = {};

    //1.each tr has the same number of ths/tds; each th/td has the same class to identify its position in the row - <th class="column-1"><th class="column-2">...<td class="column-1"><td class="column-2">
    //2.loop through each thead row, getting th class and height  
    //3.check if class already stored in myobject; if yes, check if current th height in loop is greater than value in myobject and overwrite it; if class not yet stored in myobject, add it
    //4.loop 

    $("#tablepress-999-no-2 thead tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find('th').each(function(){ 
            var currentthclass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
            var currentthheight = $(this).height();
            if(myobject.hasOwnProperty(currentthclass)){
                if($(this).height() > myobject[currentthclass]){
                    myobject[currentthclass] = currentthheight;
                }
            }else{
                myobject[currentthclass] = currentthheight;
            }
        });//end th loop
    });//end tr loop    

    //1.loop through each tbody row, getting td class and height  
    //2.check if class already stored in myobject; if yes, check if current td height in loop is greater than value in myobject and overwrite it; if class not yet stored in myobject, add it
    //3.loop    

    $("#tablepress-999-no-2 tbody tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){ 
            var currenttdclass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
            var currenttdheight = $(this).height();
            if(myobject.hasOwnProperty(currenttdclass)){
                if($(this).height() > myobject[currenttdclass]){
                    myobject[currenttdclass] = currenttdheight;
                }
            }else{
                myobject[currenttdclass] = currenttdheight;
            }
        });//end td loop
    });//end tr loop

    //1.loop through myobject getting class name and height
    //2.apply new heights to all th and td tags in table

    $.each(myobject, function(keyobj,valueobj){
        $('#tablepress-999-no-2 tbody tr td.'+keyobj).each(function(){
            $(this).height(valueobj);
        });
        $('#tablepress-999-no-2 thead th.'+keyobj).each(function(){
            $(this).height(valueobj);
        });
    });

    }else{

    //if current window size not below breakpoint, return all th and td heights to original size;

        $('#tablepress-999-no-2 tbody td').css('height','auto');    
        $('#tablepress-999-no-2 thead th').css('height','auto');

    }//end check breakpoint

    })//end resize function

});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are lot of avoidable loops in this. But since this is working for one table, you can try the following code, which loop through all tables and apply your logic.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('table.tablepress').each(function() {
        var responsivemode = $(this).attr('class').split(/ |-/);

        // ALL BREAKPOINT CODE 

        if (parseInt($(window).width()) < breakpoint) {

           var myobject = {};

            $(this).find("thead tr").each(function () {
                // full my object code
            });

            $(this).find("tbody tr").each(function () {
                // myobject logic. I didn't understand much of it :P
            });

            var $that = $(this); // refers to the table

            $.each(myobject, function (keyobj, valueobj) {
                $that.find("tbody tr td." + keyobj).each(function () {
                    $(this).height(valueobj);
                });

                $that.find("thead th." + keyobj).each(function () {
                    $(this).height(valueobj);
                });
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).find("tbody td").css('height', 'auto');
            $(this).find("thead th").css('height', 'auto');
        }
    });
});
```

`this` keyword refers to current table element currently being looped. [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), gets all the matched selector within `this` table.

Comment: thanks, but when each table has ths and tds with the same class names, my height adjustments from the last table get applied to the first table as well? I'm guessing I somehow need to empty myobject before the script is applied to the next table..?

Comment: @RichardTinkler I updated the answer. Try it and let me know

Comment: Thanks. Really close! Just one last problem: the this keyword in the $.each(myobject...) loop returns myobject and not the current table.

Comment: @RichardTinkler you're right. You can fix it by keeping a reference to the outer `this`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can change this:

```
$("#tablepress-999-no-2 thead tr")
```

to

```
$('table[id^="tablepress"] thead tr')
```

and it will apply to all tables that have an id starting with tablepress.

Comment: I would recommend they use a class rather than loop through id's.

Comment: @MasterYoda I followed his code tbh. I too would go with $(".tablepress") but didn't want to "review" his code.